# Array Sort not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that I am trying to sort but it does not seem to be working.  Some objects in the array have a `orderNum` property which I am targeting to sort.  But not all objects have this property.

I want the objects with the `orderNum` property to be sorted to the top positions in the array.

Here is a fiddle to what i have tried:  http://jsfiddle.net/7D8sN/

Here is my javascript:

```
var data = {
  "attributes": [
    {
        "value": "123-456-7890",
        "name": "phone"
    },
    {
        "value": "Something@something.com",
        "name": "email"
    },
    {
        "value": "Gotham",
        "name": "city",
        "orderNum": 1
    },
    {
        "value": "12",
        "name": "ID"
    },
    {
        "value": "Batman",
        "name": "Super Hero",
        "orderNum": 2
    }
  ]
};

data.attributes.sort( function (a, b) {
  if (a.orderNum < b.orderNum) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.orderNum > b.orderNum) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Works for me.  You really should have a value for orderNum for the undefined ones. Your getting odd results because you are comparing undefined and your sort function is returning 0 when you compare ones with values to ones without values.

Comment: @jeremy That's the whole point of his question, he wants to know how to avoid getting odd results for elements with no orderNum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if the property exists in your sort function.

```
data.attributes.sort( function (a, b) {
    if ((typeof b.orderNum === 'undefined' && typeof a.orderNum !== 'undefined') || a.orderNum < b.orderNum) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((typeof a.orderNum === 'undefined' && typeof b.orderNum !== 'undefined') || a.orderNum > b.orderNum) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I knew the sort was returning undefined but I wasn't quite sure what to do about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to check specifically for the property being `undefined`. Otherwise, both tests return `false`, so you fall through to `return 0` and treat them as equal to everything.

```
data.attributes.sort( function (a, b) {
  if (a.orderNum === undefined || a.orderNum < b.orderNum) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b.orderNum === undefined || b.orderNum < a.orderNum) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I saw that objects without orderNum were coming up as undefined but just couldn't think of what to do with it. Thank you for such a good explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether each object has the property with `hasOwnProperty("orderNum")` and then sort them accordingly.  If one has it, and the other does not, then the one with it gets put first.  I made the assumption that you were sorting with orderNum ascending.

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/RFr5N/

```
data.attributes.sort( function (a, b) {
    if ((a.hasOwnProperty("orderNum")) && (b.hasOwnProperty("orderNum")))
    {
        return a.orderNum - b.orderNum;
    }
    else if (a.hasOwnProperty("orderNum"))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (b.hasOwnProperty("orderNum"))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to 'normalize' your input :

```
data.attributes.sort( function (a, b) {
   var aOrderNum = ( a.orderNum === undefined ) ? -1 : a.orderNum ;
   var bOrderNum = ( b.orderNum === undefined ) ? -1 : b.orderNum ;
   return aOrderNum - bOderNum;
 });
```